# Calling WCF service method from browser?

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-binding

Since i am new to WCF and Having configured a WCF service endpoint in IIS at Virtual Directory Api ( url goes like

```
http://localhost/api/taskapi.svc)
```

i was looking for ways to make request through web browser something like

```
http://localhost/api/taskapi.svc/GetCompleted
```

would respond with returnd data .I know this requires the binding of web service with the webHttpBinding  but i don't know how to do it any help would be great ?

Comment: Is your question "how do you make a WCF service using webHttpBinding"? If so, what have you tried? There are fully worked examples on the web if you google "using webhttpbinding"

Answer (score 0):

Use WCFSVGHoST application to test WCF applications. Application enables you to key-in parameters value and execute method of your interest.

Link for the same:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363.aspx

Comment: I know about the "WCFSVGHOST" application it just that for further use i want to use these method by calling direcatly from the URL in SSRS that's why i want to know how to call the WCF method using the URL .